# SQL query works on SQL Server but not on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = NULL 
 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 
                    FROM table1 
                   WHERE id = @id)
```

on MySQL server but I get the follwing error message:

"Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause"

This works in Microsoft SQL Server. Any ideas on how to get it to work on MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: why not to use just: `UPDATE table1 SET column1 = NULL WHERE id = @id` ??

Comment: Not sure without seeing the data before and after but I think this could be simplified to `UPDATE table1 SET column1 = NULL WHERE id=@id` if ID is a unique value.  That will work on mysql and sql server

Comment: I cannot use
`UPDATE table1 SET column1 = NULL WHERE id = @id`
because i need to set column1 to NULL everywhere where column1 is equal to whatever value column1 is equal to in row @id. So, if in the row with id = @id, colunm1 is equal to 5, then I have to set colunm1 = NULL everywhere were column1 = 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @column1 = (SELECT column1
                FROM table1
                WHERE id = @id)


UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = NULL 
WHERE column1=@column1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra `SELECT` to the inner query. This will act as a "different" table since  you are selecting from `a` instead of `table1`:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = NULL
WHERE column1 = (
  SELECT column1 FROM (
    SELECT column1
    FROM table1
    WHERE id = @id
    )a);
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d903)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, a couple of things you can try:

1) try giving each table1 use an alias
2) using 'in' instead of '=' since you could get multiple results from the select

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.column1 = NULL WHERE t1.column1 IN (SELECT t2.column1 FROM table1 t2 WHERE id = @id)
```

3) failing these, maybe use a temp table?

Comment: Your query will give the exact same error as the original query.